# Python: Force each instance of a class to have a certain property set to the same value

Tags: python

I have a number of objects that share a particular property.  Let's call this property "Application".  At the beginning of my program, I do not know the value of Application.  At startup, I will run a routine that reveals the value of Application.  After this point, the value of Application will never change.  It is convenient for my objects to know the value of Application.  So my desired architecture is:

1. Create a Parent Class that holds the Application property.  Since there are many different objects that want to point to Application, I figured making them Children of another object would be convenient so all Child objects inherently point to Application.
2. Have a functionality such that I set Application one time and then every time I create an instance of a Child, they point to Application without the need to explicitly tell them to.

Below is an example that appears to work as I want.  The ParentClass creates a class method called set_application so that the calling program must call it at some point before invoking an instance of ParentClass.  Then the ChildClass will inherit the value of Application.

I am new to Python, so I'm curious if there are better ways to do this than what I have designed.

```
class ParentClass:

    @classmethod
    def set_application(cls, value):
        cls.Application = value

    def __init__(self):

        attr = list(__class__.__dict__.keys())
        if 'Application' in attr:
            self.Application = __class__.Application
        else:
            raise ValueError('Application must be set by using set_application method')


class ChildClass(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self, height):
        self.height = height
        super().__init__()

    def print(self):
        return vars(self)
```

Running this code:

```
Child = ChildClass(3)
```

gives:

```
ValueError: Application must be set by using set_application method
```

But running this:

```
ParentClass.set_application('ABC')
Child = ChildClass(3)
Child.print()
```

gives:

```
{'height': 3, 'Application': 'ABC'}
```

Comment: If the same value is shared by all objects, then it's pointless and inefficient to have `self.Application` exist for each object; that one assignment to `cls.Application` makes it available everywhere.

Comment: I see.  I can just refer to the class value instead of the self value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do this:

```py
class Foo:
    application = ""

    def __init__(self):
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Foo.application = "whatever"
    foo = Foo()
    print(foo.application)  # whatever
```

And if you want the inheriting classes to know `application`, too, you get that for free:

```py
class Foo:
    application = ""

    def __init__(self):
        pass


class SubFoo(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Foo.application = "whatever"

    foo = Foo()
    print(foo.application)  # whatever

    subfoo = SubFoo()
    print(subfoo.application)  # whatever
```

Another way I can think of would be to use a factory object:

```py
class FooFactory:
    def __init__(self, application):
        self.application = application

    def new_instance(self):
        return Foo(application=self.application)


class Foo:
    def __init__(self, application):
        self.application = application


if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = "whatever"

    # instantiate the factory
    factory = FooFactory(application)

    # then use that factory to create new instances of Foo
    foo_0 = factory.new_instance()
    foo_1 = factory.new_instance()
```

Comment: Okay, I see. The Child class value of application will follow the Parent class value of application, so no need to explicitly add that property to the Child object

Comment: If you found my answer useful, please, upvote it and mark it as solution. I need that reputation due to how strict moderation on this site is...